# Implementation to change current user in winforms app

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to realize to change current user in my application. I have the following code:

```
public class Framework
    {
        private MainForm mainForm = null;
        ... // other fields

        public virtual void run()
        {
            if (appInitializer!=null)
            {
                ISecurityManager securityManager = appInitializer.SecurityManager;
                if (securityManager!=null)
                {
                    if (securityManager.DoLogin())
                    {
                        RegisterDefaultActionsGroup();
                        InitializePlugins(appInitializer.Plugins);
                        // Apply rights for user
                        ActionsManager.Inst.ApplySecurity(securityManager, securityManager.CurrentUser);
                        mainForm = new MainForm();
                        mainForm.Text = appInitializer.ApplicationTitle;
                        if (appInitializer.ApplicationIcon != null)
                        {
                            mainForm.Icon = appInitializer.ApplicationIcon;
                        }
                        CorrectFormSizes(mainForm);
                        Context[Constants.MainForm] = mainForm;                     
                        MenuManager.Inst.FillMenu(DefaultGroups.MAIN_MENU, mainForm.MainMenu, ActionClick);
                        if(appInitializer.IsHaveToCreatePanelInfo) PanelInfoManager.Inst.FillInfo(mainForm);
                        if (appInitializer.IsHaveToCreateToolBar)
                        {
                            MenuManager.Inst.FillToolbar(DefaultGroups.MAIN_TOOLBAR, mainForm.MainToolStrip, ActionClick);                            
                        }
                        mainForm.MainToolStrip.Visible = mainForm.MainToolStrip.Items.Count > 0;
                        NotifyPluginsAboutShowing(appInitializer.Plugins);
                        Application.Run(mainForm);
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }

        ...//other methods
    }   

static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            Framework framework = new Framework(new EArchiveInitializer());
            framework.run();                
            }           
        }
```

In the button for change user I have:

```
 Framework.Instance.MainForm.MainMenuStrip.Items.Clear();   
 Framework.Instance.run();
```

But, I got error: `Starting a second message loop on a single thread is not a valid operation. Use Form.ShowDialog instead.`
I know that means this error, but I can't to rewrite my code.
Can you help me?
Thanks.

**SOLUTION:**
Rewrite the last line in `run` method:

```
 if (!Application.MessageLoop)
     Application.Run(mainForm);
  else
     mainForm.Show();
```

Thanks Jonathan.

Comment: Can you start another copy of the program (`Process.Start`) and kill the currently running copy?  If you want to avoid rewriting all your code to support multiple users, that might be the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: running the second instance in different thread might help

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: No, because the app is start about 10-15 second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is actually quite easy, the issue is you are calling Application.Run twice (first on load, second on the button)

A quick work around for this, would be to have the Application.Run an ApplicationContext, instead of a form initially, and from your public virtual void run() method, load the required form.

```
public class Framework 
{ 
    private MainForm mainForm = null; 
    ... // other fields 

    public virtual void run() 
    { 
        if (appInitializer!=null) 
        { 
            ISecurityManager securityManager = appInitializer.SecurityManager; 
            if (securityManager!=null) 
            { 
                if (securityManager.DoLogin()) 
                { 
                    RegisterDefaultActionsGroup(); 
                    InitializePlugins(appInitializer.Plugins); 
                    // Apply rights for user 
                    ActionsManager.Inst.ApplySecurity(securityManager, securityManager.CurrentUser); 
                    mainForm = new MainForm(); 
                    mainForm.Text = appInitializer.ApplicationTitle; 
                    if (appInitializer.ApplicationIcon != null) 
                    { 
                        mainForm.Icon = appInitializer.ApplicationIcon; 
                    } 
                    CorrectFormSizes(mainForm); 
                    Context[Constants.MainForm] = mainForm;                      
                    MenuManager.Inst.FillMenu(DefaultGroups.MAIN_MENU, mainForm.MainMenu, ActionClick); 
                    if(appInitializer.IsHaveToCreatePanelInfo) PanelInfoManager.Inst.FillInfo(mainForm); 
                    if (appInitializer.IsHaveToCreateToolBar) 
                    { 
                        MenuManager.Inst.FillToolbar(DefaultGroups.MAIN_TOOLBAR, mainForm.MainToolStrip, ActionClick);                             
                    } 
                    mainForm.MainToolStrip.Visible = mainForm.MainToolStrip.Items.Count > 0; 
                    NotifyPluginsAboutShowing(appInitializer.Plugins); 
                    mainForm.Show(); 
                }                    
            } 
        } 
    } 

    ...//other methods 
}    

static class Program 
{ 
    /// <summary> 
    /// The main entry point for the application. 
    /// </summary> 
    [STAThread] 
    static void Main() 
    { 
        Application.EnableVisualStyles(); 
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false); 

        Application.Run(new MyHiddenContext());     
        }            
    } 
public class MyHiddenContext 
    :  ApplicationContext 
{
    private static Form activeFormInstance;
    public MyHiddenContext()
    {
        this.RunFramework();
    }
    public void RunFramework()
    {
        Framework framework = new Framework(new EArchiveInitializer()); 
        this.framework.run();
        activeFormInstance = Framework.Instance.MainForm;
    }
    public static void ChangeUser()
    {
        activeFormInstance.Close();
        activeFormInstance.Dispose();
        Framework.Instance.MainForm.MainMenuStrip.Items.Clear();              
        Framework.Instance.run();           
    }
}
```

Don't quote me on the code actually working, but its more to give an idea on which way to go. The problem though is you can't call Application.Run more than once, so the principal is to have a containing instance or context (in any such sense, form, console etc)

Comment: Big Thanks. I have added the solution in question.